How to set the extent for a spatvector?
I created a spatvector of points. Using current PaleoClim, 2.5 m, bio_1.tif for raster.
library(terra)
>records
species longitude latitude
species   -62.076  -16.737
species  -60.630  -19.290

species_M <- vect(records, geom=c("longitude", "latitude"), 
                            crs=crs(shapes))

This resulted in the below figure


The points are too close to the margin. When I processed this spatvector in the stats_eval function of nichevol package, the extracted value from the raster for the point which lies at the top left becomes NA.
This code is from the stats_eval functon of nichevol package. The raster is of South American extent of the bio1 of current climate, downloaded from paleoclim website at 2.5 arc minute res.
mvar <- terra::crop(Annual_M_Temp, species_M)

VAL <- terra::extract(mvar, as.matrix(records[,c("longitude", "latitude")]))[, 1]

plot(mvar)

points(species_M)

>VAL

[1]   NA 24.5



When the spatvector crops the raster, some pixels at the top of the raster are lost, and resulted in NAs. Is there way to overcome this ?
Rahul

Your code for species_M <- vect( is correct. The plot above is the bounding box, also minimum bounding box or extent. The problem with nichevol isn't with the SpatVect, but perhaps with a rasterize step not shown, or that perhaps nichevol performs. I imagine you have many more points. See terra::ext and run min/max on your x and y, and create a receiving raster with that extent and you shouldn't 'lose your point' to NA.

Could you please check the edits and suggest ???

Link to data please so we're using the same.

All data are given. It has only two coordinates. crs is EPSG:4326

I meant of the bio_1 rast, but put it above.

Added the raster

The below approach differs from terra::extend, say as applied to the 'cropped' to ext[1] species_M as extend wouldn't include available climate data. The challenged is minimum bounding box on the points vs resolution of the raster, so adjusting the min bbox by resolution seemed to work. could be larger still, but if you have many points in records, ext(species_M_many_records) could still be treated the same.

Using PaleoClim as our raster, bio_1.tif for South America.

records <- data.frame(species = c('species', 'species'), longitude = c(-62.076, -60.630), latitude = c(-16.737, -19.290))

species_m <- vect(record, geom=c('longitude', 'latitude'), crs = crs(bio1))

bio1 <- rast('2_5m/bio_1.tif')

# per request
bio1_dagg_44 <- disagg(bio1, fact=c(4,4))
study_area <- crop(bio1_dagg_44, species_m)


# plotting separately
plot(species_m)
plot(crop(bio1, species_m), add = TRUE)


Well, that's no good, we have our species, but no climate data in the accidental plot.
bio1
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 4176, 8640, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 0.04166667, 0.04166667  (x, y)
extent      : -180.0001, 179.9999, -90.00014, 83.99986  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
source      : bio_1.tif 
name        : bio_1 
min value   :  -525 
max value   :   336

ext(species_m)
SpatExtent : -62.076, -60.63, -19.29, -16.737 (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)

ext2 = ext(species_m) * 1.04166667 # times 1 + bio1 resolution 0.04166667
plot(crop(bio1, ext2))
plot(species_m, col = 'red', add = TRUE)



If this solves your issue, please feel free to accept answer.

Thanks so much for the answer. It is neat !!. However, I do not want use a separate extent for cropping. It does not serve my purpose. I want to use "spatvector of points" for the cropping. If I can increase the extent of the spatvector of points (species_M), it would be really beneficial.

Then we explore terra::disagg and fish around for properly smaller cell resolution,

Increase the 'extent of spatvector of points' was directly demonstrated above without changing raster resolution to derive  ext2. Points have no bigness, lines have no width, both are infinitely small, but are rendered (plotted) to make sense to the eye. So the math of the minimum bounding box of points is just that, the smallest box that encloses all points, but given where those xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax are, doesn't guarantee you get a full raster cell also. Hence the two approaches above.
